# Extracting BLOB data from Excel with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, file-io

I have an excel with data exported from one MSSQL database. 
I want to get the data out of this file. The filereading is easy, everyone could do it, but is there any special work I have to de around the BLOB field to take it out safe and put it in a file. 
This field contains either a HTML or a RTF file (i have another field which tells me if it is HTML or RTF).